# Does this strategy work or is it considered overfitting?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, goodness-of-fit, overfitting

Imagine I have `X_train`, `y_train` and `X_test`, `y_test`.

I was studying neural networks and so I came up with the following strategy, however I don't know whether it is considered overfitting or not.

1. Create Neural Network number 1, call it NN1.

   a.) Train NN1 on `X_train` and `y_train`.

   b.) Test NN1 on `X_test` and `y_test`. Call the score `test_score_1` and the respective predictions `test_pred_1`.

   c.) Just for later reference, evaluate NN1 on training set, calling `train_score_1` the score and the respective predictions `train_pred_1`.
2. Create a secon Neural Network and call it NN2.

   a.) Train NN2 with input `X_train` and `train_pred_1` and with output `y_train`. (Basically the only difference is that there is a new feature. This new feature are the training predictions of NN1).

   b.) Test NN2 on inputs `X_test` and `test_pred_1`, with output `y_test`. Keep the score as `test_score_2` and the predictions as `test_pred_2`.

   c.) Now evaluate NN2 on the training set, calling `train_score_2` the score, and the respective predictions `train_pred_2`.

**My questions**

1. Does this make sense (especially if we imagine to repeat this with multiple NN, say NN3, NN4,...)?
2. Is this overfitting?
3. If we compare `test_score_1` and `test_score_2`, and we have that the second score is better (lower) than the first, does it mean we are not overfitting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Congrats, you've invented boosting :D Typically a simpler model is used, such as decision trees or a linear model.

2) It's not overfitting. You are not using y_test, nor X_test for the training of the networks (though X_test would be fine in some contexts, as a semi-supervised learning)

3) If you've trained, say, 100 networks, you have to use the 100th test predictions. Otherwise you are doing validation overfitting. You could use the validation set to determine what is the optimal number of models to ensemble. Typically, if the k-th model worsens your predictions, the residuals are just noise at that point.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, this looks to me (although I haven't implemented it yet) like a source of infinite energy, a perpetual motion machine.

So would you be able to give me a brief insight on whether there are cases in which this method might not work? Or also, why is it not indeed a "perpetual test-score improving machine" ?

Comment: Well, as I said, in practice it does not make sense to keep adding models to the ensemble, as they are trying to predict noise at some point. It is not a perpetual test scoring machine, as a) you don't train it on the test set, and at one point the new models will not have learned anything, and b) you can't select only those models that improve the test performance. So after model e.g. 20, half the models would improve your score, and half would decrease it.

Comment: @user2089357 How is this related to boosting? In each subsequent boosting iteration, the model is trained on the residuals (or some weighted combination of the actual response and the residuals) of the previous models in the ensemble. The OP is just using the output of another model as a new column in his matrix of predictors $X$.

Comment: Right, guess I misread.

Comment: Still, for a linear model, it should be equivalent.

Comment: @Josh do you think that for a non linear model it would be better to use the residuals?

Comment: @Euler_Salter Generally neural networks aren't strong candidates for boosting because they're not "weak learners" (unlike binary-split decision trees) That is, neural nets already have parameters built in that can reduce bias (which is what you get by adding boosting iterations), although these always come at the cost of increased variance (associated with overfitting). For example, if you increase the number of hidden neurons/layers or decrease regularization penalties you will (generally) reduce bias and increase variance.

Comment: @user2089357 For a linear least squares model you can't really "boost" at all, because you're solving explicitly for the parameters which minimize a convex objective function in closed form. If you try to boost, then *by definition* you'll get something suboptimal with respect to least squares. Also, I don't see why you'd get "the same thing" regardless of the model being linear or not. Compression and boosting are totally different things and are used for different purposes.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is more akin to [autoencoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder) than [boosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boosting_(machine_learning)).

Answers:

1) Possibly, and any potential benefits are likely to manifest themselves only in the case of high dimensional data (lots of predictors). A univariate response regression model simply maps $P$-dimensional predictor vectors into a $1$-dimensional response space. That is, the predictions are just the conditional expectation $E[Y]$ given parameters/weights $w$ and conditioned on predictor values $x$. This mapping (or transformation) always results in some information loss; otherwise, the original model would be perfect. So you're not providing the second model in the ensemble any additional information by compressing (to use a CS analogue) -- with *information loss* -- the information fed to the first model in the form of predictor vector $x$. There is evidence that this sort of compression can improve model performance under some circumstances -- see my Wikipedia link above.

2) The question of whether or not a model is overfit is not generally boiled down to a "yes" or "no" scenario; in this case, it's not immediately apparent that this approach would increase variance (higher variance is associated with overfitting). I think the main concern here is whether your modeling scenario is of such high dimensionality that compression is necessary; I'd worry about that before getting into the bias/variance stuff.

3) I wouldn't necessarily draw any conclusions regarding overfitting from the performance of NN2 vs NN1. There are *many* reasons why this sort of compression might make NN2 superior to NN1, and not all of them imply that compression is the best way to achieve that improvement. I think it's very likely that there are simpler ways unless you have huge dimensionality.

Comment: To be honest, I am quite new to the field so I don't know how much is huge. Depending on which features I'm using I can be between 80 and 100. My whole dataset has 3750 observations.

Comment: That's a lot of predictors for that few data points. I think the best approach is to exercise some discretion as to which predictors you think are the most informative; I'd probably try to get it under 10 to be honest. Some of your predictors may be highly collinear, which means they may reflect the same underlying process, and you can simplify things by omitting those redundant predictors. I'm not saying that autoencoding/compression are *wrong* for this, but I don't think it should be the first approach.